# The strategy about how to use the GWT and PlayFramework together

Tags: gwt, playframework

Does it make sense to use Play just for making the main layout, and use GWT-compoments (like # {some_gwt_component}) if it's needed (for example to implelemnt this component with jquery/javascript/html is quite complicated)?

Why I'm asking, because, it seems, some thinks easy to implement just with html some with gwt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think that it's a good idea to mix this techniques. Has you seen the post on [google-groups](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/3b9848cbff4a9c67/cd6051b73375396b?lnk=gst&q=Berlin#cd6051b73375396b)? It refers to information about play and gwt.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recomend it, GWT relies in the Servlet model (as far as I remember, I may be wrong) and that doesn't mix well with Play.

Also, on a more personal level, I know GWT is not really recommended by Thoughtworks as a technology (they list several issues with it) and given the technological knowledge of those guys, I usually trust their recommendations. Stay away from GWT :)

Comment: There it means that You believe in Thougthworks :) http://buzdin.blogspot.com/2010/09/thoughtworks-radar-demystified-gwt.html

Comment: @ses interesting post. I personally don't agree, as to me GWT is just another abstraction and I don't find Javascript/Jquery/other alternatives so scary as to not leave my Java bed, but I acknowledge it has its users.